# Height of Footer banner distorted after white screen of death,

Tags: css, height, screen, footer

after i had fixed my white screen of death last week.. when i open my website to continue developing today.. i noticed that the footer banner instead of covering only about 35px at the bottom of the screen... with a white space between the red header and the blue footer.... but now what i see is a massive blue footer without any stitch of white space in between the header and footer!..

this is the link to my website: http://hoho25974.staging-cloud.partnerconsole.net/

```
style.css coding. 
'* =23. Footer
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

.site-footer {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #afafaf;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

.site-footer a {
    color: #afafaf;
}

.site-info {
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-top: #eee solid 1px;
}

#colophon ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style-position: inside;
    }

#sidebar-footer {
    text-align: left;
    word-spacing: -0.29em;
    }

/* === Footer Menu  === */

.footer-menu {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.footer-menu ul {
    float: left;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.footer-menu ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    padding-right: 10px;
}'

footer-banner.css

    #colophon {
    padding: 40px 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-top: none;
    }
```

i would appreciate any pointers in order to reset the footer banner into its usual height.. i am not sure if i could use the max-height function or? and i am using the tesseract theme.

thanks very much in advance.

Comment: You should post your code here in order to the other users can help you.

Comment: thanks ricardo for the advice... will edit the original to include codes.

Comment: can anyone help with this question?

Comment: please, create a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) with your css and html